# Escape & in App.config

Tags: .net, app-config

I have the following piece of config in my App.config file:

```
<add key="ConnectionString" 
     value="INITIAL CATALOG=myDatabase;DATA SOURCE=myServer;User ID=myUser;Password=!&myPass99;"/>
```

The above connection string is rejected by Visual Studio intellisense. It says entity `myPass99` not defined. The problem is caused by the & in the password.

How do I escape it?

Comment: Try with !&amp;myPass99;

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Escape the ampersand by using `&amp;` in place of the `&`

As an FYI, see here for further characters:
[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Comment: How do I pass this value?  "USA & Canada"?  "USA"&amp"Canada"; Not working

Comment: @kudlatiger `"USA & Canada"` would turn into `"USA &amp; Canada"`

Answer (score 3):

The config file is an XML file.
Attribute values need to be encoded properly for XML.

```
e.g. If you intend to add :-
<add key="MyPassword" value="pass<word&2003"/>
Replace it with below :-
<add key="MyPassword" value="pass&lt;word&amp;2003"/>
```

Specifically :-

```
& needs to be encoded as &amp; 
< needs to be encoded as &lt;
> needs to be encoded as &gt;
" needs to be encoded as &quot;
' needs to be encoded as &apos;
```

[image]